# How to share Android lintOptions across modules

Tags: android, gradle, lint, modular, android-lint

I am building a multi-module app and in each module I have lint settings as follows

```
android {
   ...
   lintOptions {
        quiet true
        abortOnError false
        warningsAsErrors true
   }
   ...
}
```

It is tedious to repeat such settings across all modules so I'm looking for a way to write it once and share it in all modules.

I know there is something like `lint.xml` but I believe it is not for these configurations.
If it was not part of `android` block it can easily create something like `lint.gradle` and use `apply from` to link to that file from all modules. However since it is within `android`, I'm not sure if there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a `.gradle` file that contains `lintOptions` that you'd like to share, and on your module's `build.gradle` you could use `apply from`, for example, you can have `android-module-base.gradle` on your root directory, which contains the `lintOptions` you'd like to share:

```
android {
...
    lintOptions {
        quiet true
        abortOnError false
        warningsAsErrors true
    }
...
}
```

Then on your module's `build.gradle`, put this line at the beginning:

```
apply from: "$rootDir/android-module-base.gradle"
```

Comment: Thank you! I placed it at the end so it didn't work before haha.